# Django Signal on relation update

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have similar models:

```
class Basket(model.Models):
    pass


class Item(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, related_name='items')
```

I want to catch `Basket.items` update with Django Signal, but from Basket side, due to call signal once when multiple items added.

How can I catch `basket.items` relation update with a signal?

THX

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the item object in your basket using `post_signal`

```
class Basket(model.Models):
    pass

    @classmethod
    def item_added(self, **kargs):
        print karts['instance']


class Item(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, related_name='items')

post_save.connect(Basket.item_added, sender=Item)
```

Comment: why use @classmethod instead of instance method it can be a bit confusing most times